# How can i make a WPF Expander that behaves like a radio button?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a side menu with some expanders on it and i wanted my user to only select one expander at a time, i tried to style the expander control and base it on Radio Button that is based on Toggle Button but with no Success, i googled alot and found nothing, Can Somebody help please,

Here is all my XAML code with no code behind my project :

```
<Window x:Class="MyWPFApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:fa="http://schemas.awesome.incremented/wpf/xaml/fontawesome.sharp"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Background="#7f7cf1">

<Window.Resources>

    <!--MenuRadioButtons Style-->
    <Style x:Key="menuRadioButtonStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}" TargetType="RadioButton">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#707db2"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5 0 0 0"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="45"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="Tag" Value="#6673b7"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="4 0 0 0" BorderBrush="Transparent">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#bccaf1"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#bccaf1"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#bccaf1"/>
                <Setter Property="Background">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0, 0.5" EndPoint="1, 0.5">
                            <GradientStop Color="#31407b" Offset="0"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="#495385" Offset="3"/>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
                            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="4 0 0 0" BorderBrush="#a5a1f5">
                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>

        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <!--MenuRadioButtonIcons Style-->
    <Style x:Key="menuRadioButtonIconStyle" TargetType="fa:IconImage">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="23"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="23"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5 0 0 0"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type RadioButton}}}"/>
    </Style>

    <!--MenuRadioButtonTextBlock Style-->
    <Style x:Key="menuRadioButtonTextBlockStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10 0 0 0"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type RadioButton}}}"/>
    </Style>

    
    
    <!--MenuButtons Style-->
    <Style x:Key="menuButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#707db2"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5 0 0 0"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="45"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="Tag" Value="#6673b7"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="4 0 0 0" BorderBrush="Transparent">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#bccaf1"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#bccaf1"/>
                <Setter Property="Background">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0, 0.5" EndPoint="1, 0.5">
                            <GradientStop Color="#31407b" Offset="0"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="#495385" Offset="3"/>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="4 0 0 0" BorderBrush="#a5a1f5">
                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <!--MenuButtonIcons Style-->
    <Style x:Key="menuButtonIconStyle" TargetType="fa:IconImage">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="23"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="23"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5 0 0 0"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}"/>
    </Style>
    
    <!--MenuButtonTextBlock Style-->
    <Style x:Key="menuButtonTextBlockStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10 0 0 0"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}"/>
    </Style>
    
    <!--ExpanderStyle1-->
    <Style x:Key="ExpanderHeaderFocusVisual1">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Border>
                        <Rectangle Margin="0" StrokeDashArray="1 2" Stroke="Black" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" StrokeThickness="1"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="ExpanderDownHeaderStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource menuRadioButtonStyle}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
                            <Grid Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="False" Width="{Binding Path=Width, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type RadioButton}}}">
                                <Ellipse x:Name="circle" Margin="200 0 0 0" Grid.Column="2" Fill="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="19" Stroke="Transparent" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="19"/>
                                <Path x:Name="arrow" Margin="200 0 0 0" Grid.Column="2" Data="M 1,1.5 L 4.5,5 L 8,1.5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stroke="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type RadioButton}}}" SnapsToDevicePixels="false" StrokeThickness="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,0,0,0" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </RadioButton>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Data" TargetName="arrow" Value="M 1,4.5  L 4.5,1  L 8,4.5"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type RadioButton}}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type RadioButton}}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="{Binding Path=Foreground, ElementName=BtnHome}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="ExpanderStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <DockPanel>
                            <ToggleButton x:Name="HeaderSite" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplateSelector}" DockPanel.Dock="Top" FontStretch="{TemplateBinding FontStretch}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FocusVisualStyle="{StaticResource ExpanderHeaderFocusVisual1}" FontStyle="{TemplateBinding FontStyle}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" Margin="-0.8 0 0 0" MinWidth="0" MinHeight="0" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Style="{StaticResource ExpanderDownHeaderStyle1}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ExpandSite" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Focusable="false" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Visible"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="250"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     
    <!--Left Menu-->
    <Border x:Name="RightMenuBorder" CornerRadius="10 0 0 10" Grid.Column="0">
        <Border.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0, 0.5" EndPoint="1, 0.5">
                <GradientStop Color="#27396b" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#223266" Offset="2"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Border.Background>
        <StackPanel>
            <!--Drop Down Side Menu-->

            <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource menuRadioButtonStyle}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <fa:IconImage Icon="Home" Style="{StaticResource menuRadioButtonIconStyle}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Home" Style="{StaticResource menuRadioButtonTextBlockStyle}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </RadioButton>
            <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource menuRadioButtonStyle}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <fa:IconImage Icon="Home" Style="{StaticResource menuRadioButtonIconStyle}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Home" Style="{StaticResource menuRadioButtonTextBlockStyle}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </RadioButton>
            <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource menuRadioButtonStyle}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <fa:IconImage Icon="Home" Style="{StaticResource menuRadioButtonIconStyle}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Home" Style="{StaticResource menuRadioButtonTextBlockStyle}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </RadioButton>
            <Expander Style="{DynamicResource ExpanderStyle1}" Background="Transparent">
                <Expander.Header>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="-5 0 0 0">
                        <fa:IconImage Icon="DollarSign" Style="{StaticResource menuRadioButtonIconStyle}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="Sales" Style="{StaticResource menuRadioButtonTextBlockStyle}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Expander.Header>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource menuButtonStyle}">
                        <TextBlock Text="New Invoice" Style="{StaticResource menuButtonTextBlockStyle}" Margin="62 0 0 0"/>
                    </Button>
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource menuButtonStyle}">
                        <TextBlock Text="Manage Invoices" Style="{StaticResource menuButtonTextBlockStyle}" Margin="62 0 0 0"/>
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>
            </Expander>
            <Expander Style="{DynamicResource ExpanderStyle1}" Background="Transparent">
                <Expander.Header>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="-5 0 0 0">
                        <fa:IconImage Icon="DollarSign" Style="{StaticResource menuRadioButtonIconStyle}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="Sales" Style="{StaticResource menuRadioButtonTextBlockStyle}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Expander.Header>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource menuButtonStyle}">
                        <TextBlock Text="New Invoice" Style="{StaticResource menuButtonTextBlockStyle}" Margin="62 0 0 0"/>
                    </Button>
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource menuButtonStyle}">
                        <TextBlock Text="Manage Invoices" Style="{StaticResource menuButtonTextBlockStyle}" Margin="62 0 0 0"/>
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>
            </Expander>
            <Expander Style="{DynamicResource ExpanderStyle1}" Background="Transparent">
                <Expander.Header>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="-5 0 0 0">
                        <fa:IconImage Icon="DollarSign" Style="{StaticResource menuRadioButtonIconStyle}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="Sales" Style="{StaticResource menuRadioButtonTextBlockStyle}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Expander.Header>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource menuButtonStyle}">
                        <TextBlock Text="New Invoice" Style="{StaticResource menuButtonTextBlockStyle}" Margin="62 0 0 0"/>
                    </Button>
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource menuButtonStyle}">
                        <TextBlock Text="Manage Invoices" Style="{StaticResource menuButtonTextBlockStyle}" Margin="62 0 0 0"/>
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>
            </Expander>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
    
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way you could do it. Each Expander will have to use the Expanded event handler for this to work. Whenever an Expander is expanded, all the others will be collapsed.

XAML:

```xml
<StackPanel>
    <Expander Expanded="Expander_Expanded"></Expander>
    <Expander Expanded="Expander_Expanded"></Expander>
    <Expander Expanded="Expander_Expanded"></Expander>
</StackPanel>
```

Code behind:

```cs
private void Expander_Expanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var stackPanel = (sender as Expander).Parent as StackPanel;
    foreach(var child in stackPanel.Children)
    {
        if(child is Expander && child != sender)
        {
            ((Expander)child).IsExpanded = false;
        }
    }
}
```